# How could I use ZeroMQ on an AWS load balancer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, zeromq, amazon-elb, internal-load-balancer

I have two EC2 instances ( vm1, vm2 ) and an internal network load balancer in my private subnet in VPC. In vm1, I run a program to connect an AWS load balancer:

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    socket.connect("tcp://aws-loadbalancer-dns-name:1111")

    for i in range(5):
        socket.send_string(str(i))
        msg = socket.recv()
        print('receive respond:', msg)
```

In vm2, I also run a program:

```
import zmq
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:1111")

    while True:
        msg = socket.recv()
        print('receive request:', msg)
        socket.send_string(str(msg))
        time.sleep(1)
```

It seems to be failed.

How could I adjust my setting in AWS?

Or is there something wrong in my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you think zeromq == echo server?

Answer (score 1):

### Part I: " *Is there something wrong in my code?* " :

No, the ZeroMQ use-case code seems trouble-free.

Feel free to add as many debugging tracepoints into the MCVE-source as needed on the hunt, so as to document in detail, where it gets and what actual **`ZMQError()`** gets reported on the fly:

```
[ 'EADDRINUSE',          #           L3
  'EADDRNOTAVAIL',       #           L3
  'ECONNREFUSED',        #           L3
  'ENETDOWN',            # L1 / L2 / L3
  'ENODEV',              # L1
  'EFAULT',
  'EFSM',                # ZMQ Finite State Machine not in a state to obey this
  'EAGAIN',              # ZMQ Context() blocked
  'EINPROGRESS',
  'EINVAL',              # ZMQ did not recognise a valid value in param
  'EMTHREAD',
  'ENOBUFS',             # resources
  'ENOMEM',              # resources
  'ENOCOMPATPROTO',      # ZMQ protocol-handshaking
  'EPROTONOSUPPORT',     # ZMQ protocol 
  'ENOTSOCK',            # ZMQ resource - not recognised as an "own" socket
  'ENOTSUP',             # ZMQ cannot support a request
  'ETERM',               # ZMQ Context() already entered into a .term()-state
   ...
   ]
```

---

### Part II: " *How could I adjust my setting in AWS?* " :

This part is a bit tricky.

First, consult your contracted parameters. If AWS operator does not permit you to initiate TCP/IP-services among instances, no other step but a contract renegotiation ( selecting other, less restricted product ) may help.

In case TCP/IP-services are not blocked, consult with the AWS operator Support line, what port-numbers are permitted on respective instances. Operating system, besides the operator policies mentioned above, may have some further restricted port-number ranges and if your application uses an O/S-blocked **`<transport-class>://<address>:<port#>`** ( being `== 1111` in the use-case MCVE above ), any attempt will systematically fail right due to attempt to use a forbidden resource ( changing the `<port#>` being the easiest remedy, isn't it? ).

For any other cases, the **`ZMQError`** will help you diagnose the root-cause of the operations blocked. Feel free to add as many debugging tracepoints as needed on the hunt.